# Web service time out errors in Delphi

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, network-programming

I have a client application that makes SOAP requests. I have set the timeout to 20 minutes. However, sometimes I see the timeout error occurring after 10 seconds.
I have the following in code:

```
RIO.HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 1200000
```

Do I need to set the `ConnectTimeout` and `SendTimeOut`? Currently they are set to the default values of 0. What difference would setting these make?

I am using Delphi 2007.

Looking further at the error message I see I get "The operation timed out....". So should I be setting my `ReceiveTimeOut` to zero since I really do not want any timeout at all?

Comment: We are currently sending large amounts of data to the server, should I just set ReceiveTimeOut to 0? However that does not still explain with I get "occasionally" a time out after 10 secs...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CodeGear's `SOAPHTTPTrans` implementation sets timeouts globally, not per session.  Here's the relevant code from `THTTPReqResp.Send`:

```
{ Timeouts }
if FConnectTimeout > 0 then
  Check(not InternetSetOption({Request}nil, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FConnectTimeout), SizeOf(FConnectTimeout)));
if FSendTimeout > 0 then
  Check(not InternetSetOption({Request}nil, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FSendTimeout), SizeOf(FSendTimeout)));
if FReceiveTimeout > 0 then
  Check(not InternetSetOption({Request}nil, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FReceiveTimeout), SizeOf(FReceiveTimeout)));
```

What I've had to do to is use the `OnBeforePost` handler to set the timeouts:

```
transport.OnBeforePost := configureHttpRequest;

procedure Tsomething.configureHttpRequest(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
begin
  InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FconnectTimeoutMS), SizeOf(FconnectTimeoutMS));
  InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FsendTimeoutMS), SizeOf(FsendTimeoutMS));
  InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FreceiveTimeoutMS), SizeOf(FreceiveTimeoutMS));
end;
```

The MSDN documentation for these options is found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385328%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much glob. Any ideas why I would get a timed out operation even after a few seconds?

Comment: no, not 10 seconds.  the default timeout varies with the installed IE version -- with IE7 it's 30 seconds.  and as the default code sets the timeout globally, you may hit problems should other code change the timeout.  i always explicitly set the timeout as per the code in my answer.